# Wordpress Posts Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, post, shortcode

I would like to display posts within other posts and pages in WordPress without the use of a plugin. I've searched this site (and others) but haven't found a definitive answer to what I am looking for.

I'd like to display a short-code within posts and pages in this fashion:

`[insert_post id="99"]` 
where 99 is the ID of the post (or page, if possible).

I'd like to pull in the following:
title,
the content (first 30 words),
read more button,
featured image (thumb).

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the effort tried to get results ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the `shortcode` first. This code goes in your `functions.php`. Here is a basic example to achieve what you are trying to achieve:

```
function insert_post_shortcode_function( $atts ) {
    $attributes = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '' // attribute_name => default_value
    ), $atts );

    $return = '';

    $post = get_post($attributes['id']);

    $return .= get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);

    $return .= $post->post_title;

    $return .= $post->post_content;

    $return .= '<a href="'.get_the_permalink($post->ID).'">Read more</a>';

    return $return;
}
add_shortcode( 'insert_post', 'insert_post_shortcode_function' );
```

Now you can use `[insert_post id="x"]` in your post's content.

More on creating shortcodes - https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Nice answer but rather than accessing post_content directly i think i would apply the content filters to it see [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/)